# display content in tableview having exactly two columns in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a json response which has images and other content of which I want to show images in tableview but it should consists of only two columns with unlimited rows.

Can anyone help on this query?

**Code:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) 
{ 
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ 
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE, 
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE, 
        layout: "horizontal" 
    });

    var myImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({ 
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE, 
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE, 
        image : jsonResponse[i].cover_image_url 
    }); 

    row.add(myImage); 
    data.push(row); 
} 
table.setData(data); 
win2.add(tableview);
```

Comment: Post your code what  you've tried

Comment: `  for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
     width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
     height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
     layout: "horizontal"
    });
    var myImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
     width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
     height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
     image : jsonResponse[i].cover_image_url

    });
    row.add(myImage);

    data.push(row);

   }
   table.setData(data); 
   win2.add(tableview);  `

Comment: hi @buntyrohra , try using Alloy instead of classic. Also please add the code to the question

Comment: @RenePot Can you please give the sample code?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/kX5smux.png)


The link is the proper reference of what I want.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
var rowHeight = 50; // just pick the right height here
var imageRowIsFull = false;
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ 
        width : '100%', 
        height : rowHeight, 
        layout: "horizontal" 
    });
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) 
{ 
    var myImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({ 
        width : '50%', 
        height : rowHeight, 
        image : jsonResponse[i].cover_image_url 
    }); 

    myImage.addEventListener('click', function(event){
          //event handling here
    });

    row.add(myImage); 
    imageRowIsFull = false;

    if ( (i + 1) % 2 == 0) { //this will add a new row every 2 items.
       imageRowIsFull = true; 
       data.push(row); 
       row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ 
            width : '100%', 
            height : rowHeight, 
            layout: "horizontal" 
       });
    }
} 

if (!imageRowIsFull) { //do not forget to add the last row
       data.push(row); 
}
table.setData(data); 
win2.add(tableview);
```

Comment: Hey it is working.
Thanks for the code.
But the alignment is not looking good as per the image provided in the above comment.
Can you help me to give layout as per the link provided?
[link](http://i.imgur.com/kX5smux.png)

Comment: I don't understand what do you need

Comment: I just want your code to be arranged like the image which is provided in the link...
alignment of image view is not proper.
It would be great if you provide alignment as per the image in the link.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/kX5smux.png)

Comment: sorry, mate. I'm not going to code for you :) Layouting is not that hard to understand. Once it gets into your head, you'll be able to layout anything using Titanium

Comment: Thats ok..
Thanks for the code.
If possible can you please help me out in telling how to get click event of each image because in this case I will be getting row event.
It would be great.
Thanks for the help.